# Help ID this plant, quite possibly a weed

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this plant near my South Indian home in [Kerala](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala), India. Most probably it could be some sort of weed. Anyhoo, is this plant of any medical or commercial value? Is it a remedy for something?

- It has a white tap root with little veins off the main root
- It has a really small yellow flower
- It's leaves are similar to that of a clover, except for that it has three to five leaves

[image: The plant]
[image: The roots of the plant]
[image: The flower (or is it a bud?)]
[image: The leaf design]

***Merci d'avance!***

(*P.S. Forgive me if this is some very common plant that I should know about, I'm in 7th grade.*)

Comment: So long since I've heard weed for this other meaning..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume it is Cleome viscosa, the Asian spiderflower.

[image]

> It is commonly found in rainy season.

Medicinal uses:

> The crushed leaves have been investigated as a treatment on stored seeds of cowpea, to prevent weevil infestation.
>
> The leaves are use as external application to wounds and ulcers. The seed are anrhelmintic and carminative Juice of leaves is used as remedy against discharge of puss from the ear.

Identified by the following features-

1. Palmate leaves
2. Colour of flower especially the brown part at the base
3. Herbaceous habit

References:

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleome_viscosa)
2. [Flowersofindia.net](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Asian%20Spider%20Flower.html)