# What is the name of this plant with 4-5 lobed leaves?

Tags: species-identification

Location is India, It has **4-5** lobed leaves with flowers & **pointy** seed pods.

[image]

I am thinking it is ***Wild raddish.***

Comment: 50 mins still no answers, what more else details to ID this plant?. Image is not blur very clear.

Comment: please include the location of the plant and preferably some info about the surrounding habitat. Also, what are the sizes of the leaves and petals?  Do you have any closeup photos of the leaves or flowers? (Include this info by editing the question directly, do  not add it in the comments). Thanks.

Comment: Also, be patient. We're not some  sort of service -- we all have busy lives. But don't worry, when  you get your answer, it should be well supported

Comment: Looks like [Asian spiderflower](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/53243/16460).

Comment: Thank You. It is [**Asian spiderflower**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/53243/16460)

Comment: Yeah strongly looks [Cleome viscosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleome_viscosa), very common in West Bengal, too. Another species, [C. rutidosperma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleome_rutidosperma) that have 3-lobbed leaves and violet flowers, is also very common in India.

Comment: It is not member of radish family (brassicaceae) but it is a close relative of that.